# Como saber cuando un numero random ya fue generado JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que genera numeros con el metodo de Medios Cuadrados, la cosa esta en que debe parar cuando se repita la semilla o un numero random generado se repita.
Alguien podria ayudarme a como hacerlo?

```
    long elevado, numeroM,semillaVali;
    String semilla, snumero2, snumero3;
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese un numero de 4 cifras: ");
        semilla=sc.next();
        do {
            int tam1=semilla.length();
            numeroM=Integer.parseInt(semilla);
            elevado=(long)Math.pow(numeroM, 2);
            snumero2=String.valueOf(elevado);
            int tam2=snumero2.length();
            if(tam2<8) {
                System.out.println("El numero al cuadrado es 0"+elevado);
            } else {
                System.out.println("El numero al cuadrado es "+elevado);
            }
            int primerC=(tam2-tam1) / 2;
            snumero3=snumero2.substring(primerC,primerC+tam1);
            System.out.println(snumero3);
            semilla = snumero3;
        semillaVali = Long.parseLong(snumero3);
        } while (semillaVali !=0 );
```

Comment: Para saber si un valor random se ha repetido, debes almacenar cada valor generado en una lista. Luego basta con verificar si el nuevo valor que se obtiene ya está en la lista. Obviamente la lista inicia vacía. Saludos

Comment: Podria explicarme como verificar si el numero esta en la lista?  Porfavor

Comment: Para verificar si un número se encuentra dentro de la lista usa  el método contains()